# Высота слайдов в owl carousel

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, owl-carousel

Всем привет кто нибудь знает как в owl-carousel2 сделать так чтобы высота всех слайдов была одинаковой в зависимости от контента в самом высоком слайде (все остальные слайды по меньше подстраивали свою высоту и становились по высоте как самый высокий слайд)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<div class="owl-carousel owl-car-first">
  <div class = "first_slide">
    1
    <br>
    2
 </div>

  <div class = "second_silde">
    1
  </div>
</div>
```

Вот абстрактное объяснение ситуации, чтобы было понятно

Comment: а можно пример ваш? - есть просто догадка, что это регулирует один из параметров

Comment: Сейчас прикреплю слайд по меньше и побольше

Comment: вот в 1-ом слайде контента больше чем во 2-ом и из-за этого получается вот так

Comment: Меня код больше интересовал)

Comment: дайте пример кода, но почти уверен, что данная проблема решается одной строчкой в css

Comment: Вы меня не поняли. Отредактируйте вопрос6 добавьте в него ваш код _HTML_ + _CSS_

Comment: окей, вот самая простая ситуация когда достигается такая ситуация